# How to Foreach loop through Laravel collection.?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i m a beginner at laravel. using 5.5 . i have this collection return by my controller :

```
$products = Product::with('bazar.resellers')->take(2)->get();
dd($products);
//return view('shop.index')->with('products', $products);
```

which basically is three tables with nested relations. Note the **relations** lists in the code below. i want to access data(all columns in red colour) from every model i have in the collection i.e. Product, bazar and reseller.

Relationships are quite fine. but how to retrieve it from a collection? i dunno how foreach loops play with a collection.

```
Collection {#578 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => Product {#487 ▼
  #fillable: array:7 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2018-04-27 12:54:41"
    "updated_at" => "2018-04-27 12:54:41"
    "imgp" => "shirt.jpg"
    "title" => "shirt1"
    "Prod_descript" => "shirt1 is a good shirt"
    "price" => 10
    "reseller_id" => 1
    "City_id" => 1
    "bazar_id" => 1
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▼
    "bazar" => Bazar {#523 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "Bazarname" => "Saddar"
        "Bazarlat" => null
        "Bazarlong" => null
        "created_at" => null
        "updated_at" => null
        "City_id" => 1
      ]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "resellers" => Collection {#574 ▼
          #items: array:1 [▼
            0 => Reseller {#564 ▼
              #guard: "reseller"
              #fillable: array:12 [▶]
              #hidden: array:2 [▶]
              #connection: "mysql"
              #table: null
              #primaryKey: "id"
              #keyType: "int"
              +incrementing: true
              #with: []
              #withCount: []
              #perPage: 15
              +exists: true
              +wasRecentlyCreated: false
              #attributes: array:15 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "Fname" => "talha"
                "Lname" => "ali"
                "email" => "p@g.com"
                "password" => "$2y$10$M7wOmSouxSAYADN7NeFdSObT8fGwkEOFxVmOgcNSWvrixWCDtA/1S"
                "mobile_no" => "03169880008"
                "landline_no" => "0987654"
                "shop_name" => "MyTestSHop"
                "NIC_no" => "170178359437589754"
                "shop_address" => "University Town, Peshawar, Pakistan"
                "remember_token" => "wrb3nOwOWQcTuoF0P9KnaknwpOxfpTHt4gkShUmTzkR2Df9A7pPY5shBq6pQ"
                "created_at" => "2018-04-27 12:42:25"
                "updated_at" => "2018-04-27 12:42:25"
                "City_id" => 1
                "bazar_id" => 1
              ]
              #original: array:15 [▶]
              #changes: []
              #casts: []
              #dates: []
              #dateFormat: null
              #appends: []
              #dispatchesEvents: []
              #observables: []
              #relations: []
              #touches: []
              +timestamps: true
              #visible: []
              #guarded: array:1 [▶]
              #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
1 => Product {#488 ▶}
]
}
```

the code i have tried is not working!

```
@foreach($products as $product)
<h1>{{ $product->title }}</h1>

@foreach($product->bazar as $bazar)
    <h3>{{ $bazar->Bazarname }}</h3>

    @foreach($bazar->resellers as $reseller)
        <p>{{ $reseller->Fname }}</p>
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

@endforeach

Comment: `$product->bazar` is a single object, not a collection.

Comment: You should regard the error you have got.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir so collection are for multiple objects ? what other function can i use to take first two rows of my table ? else than get () ? since it always return a collection.

Comment: @SaidbakR it gives a blank page. because i dont understand the concept of collection and looping through it. the documentation is some how not so much helping for me. my english is weak. can someone in easy words tell me whats this collection thing used for ?

Comment: A collection is just the Laravel version of an array. Your collection handing is fine. My point was that `$product->bazar` is *not* a collection, so you have to use `$product->bazar->Bazarname` and `@foreach($product->bazar->resellers`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thankyou so much brother `@foreach($product->bazar->resellers` worked for me. now i m starting to understand that ever new new model is a property inside the original model in my case 
i actually `get()` a special array. of products where each product is:
 `Product{ 'coloumnsOfproduct':'valuesofproducts', 'bazar': '{'columnsofbazar':'valuesofbazar', 'reseller':'{'columnsOfreseller':'valuesofreseller'}'}' }`
plz tell me if am getting its right concept now ?

Comment: Yes, that's right ;-)

Comment: thank bro @JonasStaudenmeir stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

If product has single bazar,then you don't need to use foreach on `$product->bazar`. You just need to use bazar property directly. and if product has many bazars, then update your product model `bazar()` method like:

```
public function bazars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bazar::class);
}
```

It returns collection of bazars and then you can run loop on that.

Comment: Thanks Brother for the help. the product model  `belongsto(App\Reseller)
belongsto(App\City)
belongsto(App\Bazar)` 
but when i do `$product->bazar->Bazarname;`  it returns error
trying

Comment: Does this product have a `bazar`? What's the result of `{{ dd($product->bazar) }}`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks for your help brother. yes this product belongs to a bazar. if i do a query i.e. `$products = Product::with('bazar.resellers')->take(2)->get();` and then 
`foreach ($products as $product) {
   dd($product->bazar); }`
 then it returns a whole bunch of results. including that bazar model.

Comment: What error does `$product->bazar->Bazarname` give you?